# How to calculate probability in normal distribution by Matlab?

Tags: matlab, probability, normal-distribution

I'm new to Matlab and I would appreciate if someone could help. 
The problem:

IQ coefficients are Normally distributed with a mean of 100 and a standard deviation of 15. Calculate the probability that a randomly drawn person from this population has an IQ greater than 110 but smaller than 130. You can achieve this using one line of matlab code.
What does this look like?

I tried like this:

```
>> max(normpdf(linspace(110,130,100),100,15))
ans =
    0.0213
```

But not sure if it is correct..

I would be thankful for any help!

Comment: Note that a probability density function (PDF) ([see wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)) is an intensity of a probability (actually, a derivative of a probability).  See [this question & answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/can-a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-be-ok) on CrossValidated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets check:

```
N=1e7;                          %Number of "experimental" samples
iq = randn(1,N)*15 + 100;       %Create a set of IQ values
p = sum(iq>=110 & iq<=130)/N    %Determine how many are in range of interest.
```

This returns a number around 23%.

Comment: @GyuzalR This is an empirical approach that is unnecessary and only approximate.  The OP's question is answerable exactly with the cumulative distribution function. This does serve to validate [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15730591/8239061).

Answer (score 4):

This is most efficiently handled using the normal **cumulative** density function.

```
normcdf(130,100,15) - normcdf(110,100,15)
```

Or if you prefer to manually convert these to "Z" scores then you can use the single argument version of the cdf.

```
normcdf(30/15) - normcdf(10/15)
```

In either case the answer is 0.2297, so about 23%.

Comment: I believe there is a typo here....@Stuart means the *cumulative distribution function* ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)). The approach is correct.